# How to set the execution policy for the powershell_ise when it is launching?

Tags: powershell

PowerShell 4.0

It is possible to set the execution policy for the *process* scope when the `powershell` host is launching. For example:

```
powershell -executionpolicy bypass
```

I want to do the same for `powershell_ise` host, but it hasn't the `ExecutionPolicy` key. Is exist the similar method of the execution policy setting for that host (maybe through the other way instead of keys)?

**P.S.** Of course, I can type this `cmdlet` manually, when `powershell_ise` will be launched, but I would want to create the separate *label* on my desktop for launching `powershell_ise` with this setting when I need it.

Comment: Process scope execution policy controlled by `PSExecutionPolicyPreference` environment variable. You can set this environment variable to desired value before starting PowerShell ISE.

Comment: Hm... I read that the `env:PSExecutionPolicyPreference` cannot be changed "manualy" in the powershell session... I'll try to do it  *before* the PowerShell ISE starting, thank you for the advice.

Comment: @PetSerAl, it works fine, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process scope execution policy is controlled by the `PSExecutionPolicyPreference` environment variable. You can set this environment variable to desired value before starting PowerShell ISE.

Answer (score 0):

Help is needed to set all of the ExecutionPolicies to "Restricted[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9NUR.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).